# How to make this three components into a multistep form wizard

Tags: vue.js

Here I have made three components. That is displaying one after other I want to make this component to display like multistep form. like step1, step2, step3, Here if we click next button from step1 than it should go to step2. and so on..., So if any one have an idea on this pleas help me thank you.

```
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-form-generator@2.3.4/dist/vfg.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-form-generator@2.3.4/dist/vfg.css"></script>
</head>
<div class="container" id="app">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Form</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <vue-form-generator :schema="schema" :model="model" :options="formOptions"></vue-form-generator>
    </div>
  </div>

      <vue-form-generator :schema="schema" :model="model" :options="formOptions"></vue-form-generator>


      <vue-form-generator :schema="schema" :model="model" :options="formOptions"></vue-form-generator>

      <vue-form-generator :schema="schema" :model="model" :options="formOptions"></vue-form-generator>

<script>
```

**vue.js**

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",

    components: {
        "vue-form-generator": VueFormGenerator.component
    },

    data() {
            return {
        model: {
            id: "",
            name: "",
            password: "",
            age: "",
            skills: "",
            email: "",
            status: ""
        },
        schema: {
            fields: [{
                type: "input",
                inputType: "text",
                label: "ID",
                model: "id",
                readonly: true,
                featured: false,
                disabled: true
            }, {
                type: "input",
                inputType: "text",
                label: "Name",
                model: "name",
                readonly: false,
                featured: true,
                required: true,
                disabled: false,
                placeholder: "User's name",
            }, {
                type: "input",
                inputType: "password",
                label: "Password",
                model: "password",
                min: 6,
                required: true,
            }, {
                type: "input",
                inputType: "number",
                label: "Age",
                model: "age",
                min: 18,
                validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.number
            }, {
                type: "input",
                inputType: "email",
                label: "E-mail",
                model: "email",
                placeholder: "User's e-mail address",
                validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.email
            }, {
                type: "checklist",
                label: "Skills",
                model: "skills",
                multi: true,
                required: true,
                multiSelect: true,
                values: ["HTML5", "Javascript", "CSS3", "CoffeeScript", "AngularJS", "ReactJS", "VueJS"]
            }, {
               type: "switch",
                label: "Status",
                model: "status",
                multi: true,
                readonly: false,
                featured: false,
                disabled: false,
                default: true,
                textOn: "Active",
                textOff: "Inactive"
            }]
        },

        formOptions: {
            validateAfterLoad: true,
            validateAfterChanged: true
        }
            };
    },


});
```

Comment: You can use the vue-step-wizard package.
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-step-wizard-form-with-validation-ghz85?

Comment: Are your forms basically identical (as your example implies) or will they contain different inputs, etc.?

Comment: In a above code I want to align two input fields side by side. How we can achieve that